# What does "over at" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I just read this sentence:

> I've already spoken to Nick ***over at*** the C.I.A.

And such a small question, what does over mean here? I can't find a suitable value, I will be glad to get a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"over" carries the sense of "over there".  This is a casual expression. It suggests that the CIA office is in a different building, and is separate from where the speaker is.